# Send android apk to multiple devices

Tags: android, deployment

I have 150 android devices (all same brand and model) in a school environment (each student has one). I would like to be able to install one or more apps to all of them with no or minimal actions from the students.

The devices have google play installed, but most of the students don't have google accounts.

Something like a private repo comes to mind.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are few great tool that can be used as fast distribution for testers, so you could use them as well for students. Eg. http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/ for free, or HockeyApp, which isn't free. Afaik they're offering distribution via email and automatic updates, if theres such option enabled.